# Change font increment for WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I'm using a WPF RichTextBox control to input some text with user formatting capability, including font size adjustment.  The built-in commands for IncreaseFontSize and DecreaseFontSize will adjust the font size by 0.75pt each time the command is executed.  I would like to increase the granularity to 2pt.

Can this be done without implementing my own custom commands?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the value is hard-coded and you cannot change it. The fastest way to implement this is to use the TextRange class. Something like this:

```
var range = new TextRange( rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd );
range.ApplyPropertyValue( TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 30.0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work for InlineContainers that are text blocks